# Django dynamic permissions for instance of custom model

Tags: permissions, django-1.6

I have a model of which instances are created by my site users. User can also share those instances of that model with other users. I will create functions like `can_view()`, `can_change()`, `can_delete()` for them. I know how to do it with another relation model but I am wondering if current Django permission framework can be used to solve this.

I read the docs and it seems [this is possible](http://scrible.com/s/47Fyy) but I want to double check it with you and please point me to the right doc page which has some code examples :)

I know many similar questions are posted on SO before but answers suggest to use custom django packages which I already know which one to use but I am interested to solve this with build in Django permission framework.